# WickedPDF unpatched on osx

Tags: wicked-pdf

I am trying to html to pdf on mac osx. I write this command,

```
$ wkhtmltopdf --header-center "google"  http://www.google.com google.pdf
```

but I saw the error,

```
The switch --header-center, is not support using unpatched qt, and will be ignored.Loading page (1/2)
Printing pages (2/2)                                               
Done
```

What is the problem? How should I fix?

Answer (score 2):

Install Qt from https://code.google.com/p/wkhtmltopdf/wiki/compilation yourself. Hopefully this will do.

Comment: yes the link has been shifted. You can install wkhtmltopdf 0.12.1 (with patched qt) and all will be good. Here is the link http://wkhtmltopdf.org/downloads.html